# I am trying to share a file between windows 7 (host) and Ubuntu 12.04.4 (guest), using Virtual Box 4.3.12

Tags: 12.04, windows-7, permissions, virtualbox, shared-folders

I have put the folder (winshare), it has some data in it, that I need under Virtual Machine---Settings---Shared Folders---Machine  Folders, and in Ubuntu I have created the directory ~/media/winshare. The guest additions have been installed and I ran the command, sudo mount -t vboxsf winshare /media/winshare  , from there the command executes just fine, no errors, but when I move into ~/media/winshare the data under my windows winshare file does not show up in ubuntu. Why is this? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you add your user to the `vboxsf` group in Ubuntu? What is the output of `ls -al ~` and `ls -al ~/media/winshare` and `ls -al /media`? Are you confusing `~/media` and not `/media` (`/media` is the default mount point)?

Comment: btw it might be easier for you (no manual mount required) if you go to *VirtualBox Settings  > Shared Folder* and select "Auto-mount" yes.

Comment: It is solved! It turns out I did not have the permission to view the shared files

Comment: So the answer was adding your user to the `vboxsf` group?

Comment: It was weird I could not see it in the GUI, but was still able to cd to it

Comment: So I just set the path to it on the program I was using and it read it just fine

Comment: Going back adding my user to vboxsf group did work, so thanks again

Comment: Good. I added that as an answer, please accept it to help others with this problem find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default VirtualBox Shared Folders are only accessible to members of the `vboxsf` group. To add your user to the vboxsf group in Ubuntu do:

```
sudo adduser $(whoami) vboxsf
```